# Вывод таблицы на элемент body через скрипт

Tags: javascript, html, table

Я новичок в программировании и в том числе в JS и HTML. На курсе дали задание и я не могу понять, как с ним справиться.

В пустом HTML файле (не используя никаких тегов в `body`), с помощью скрипта вывести таблицу 3х3 с буквами внутри. Я могу сделать таблицу в `body`, но не понимаю, как вставить её в скрипт и вывести на экран. Кто нибудь может объяснить или дать направление.

Я приблизительно понимаю, что мне нужно использовать `documents.body.innerHTML = "";` Но не понимаю как его использовать.
Вот код таблицы:

```
<table border=1 id="1">
    <tr> 
    <th> A </th>
    <th> B </th>
    <th> C </th>
</tr>
<tr> 
    <th> D </th>
    <th> E </th>
    <th> F </th>
</tr>
<tr> 
    <th> H </th>
    <th> I </th>
    <th> G </th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ, на самом деле, может варьироваться от простого, до многострочного объяснения.

Простой вариант:

```js
window.onload = function(){

    let template = `<table border=1 id="1">
        <tr> 
        <th> A </th>
        <th> B </th>
        <th> C </th>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <th> D </th>
        <th> E </th>
        <th> F </th>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <th> H </th>
        <th> I </th>
        <th> G </th>
    </tr>`;

    document.body.innerHTML = template;
}
```

Скрипт в вставляется в тег `head` примерно так:

```
<head>
    <script>
        // Тут как раз скрипт
    </script>
</head>
```

---

Более сложные, тоже используя *Javascript*, но используя **[document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/document.createElement)**, **[appendChild](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp)**, **[append/prepend, before/after, replaceWith](https://learn.javascript.ru/multi-insert#append-prepend-before-after-replacewith)** и другие методы работы с DOM

```js
function tableCreate() {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var tbl = document.createElement('table');   
    tbl.setAttribute('border', '1');
    var tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
    var letterCount = 0;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {            
            var td = document.createElement('td');                
            var t = document.createTextNode(String.fromCharCode(65 + letterCount++));
            
            td.appendChild(t);             
            tr.appendChild(td)            
        }
        
        tbdy.appendChild(tr);
    }
    
    tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
    body.appendChild(tbl)
}

tableCreate();
```

```css
td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

можно с помощью конкатенации чем и является в некоторых ситуациях
оператор сложения плюс " + "  и с использованием экранирования " \ "

```html
<script>
 document.body.innerHTML = "<table border=1 id=\"1\">" +
 "<tr>" +
  "<th> A </th>" +
  "<th> B </th>" +
  "<th> C </th>" +
 "<\/table>"
</script>
```

подключить скрипт можно двумя способами ,
либо прописать тег скрипт `<script> cod </script>` и в нем писать код либо
подключить файл с расширением js
указав до него путь

```html
<script src="../../../home/desktop/main.js"></script>
```

вот более сложный вариант

```html
<script>
 var a = 'A'
 var b = 'B'
 var c = 'C'
 
 document.body.innerHTML = "<table border=1 id=\"1\">" +
 "<tr>" +
  "<th>" + a + "</th>" +
  "<th>" + b + "</th>" +
  "<th>" + c + "</th>" +
 "<\/table>"
</script>
```